# Checking if a non-integer number exists in a string during eval()

Tags: python, eval

Given an input of various layouts of bracketed equations in string form, e.g. `'(3-7)/5'`, I'm looking to check if at any point in it's evaluation, it would contain a non-integer number.

For instance, `'(3/2)+1'` immediately contains a `float`, and remains a `float` when fully evaluated, that being `2.5`. But something like `'(5/2)*2'` is briefly a float and then could be evaluated as an integer, or, by the `eval()` function, `'(4/2)+3'` would be a float after evaluation, even though no non-integer number exists during it's evaluation.

The only thing I could think of when trying to solve this would be to search the string for the `/` operator, and then find the smallest set of brackets that would involve that division. So for `'(2+1)/4'` it would first have to evaluate the `2+1` and then could check for non-integer division...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Look at `sympy` and its `simplify`-method.

Comment: Are you looking for anything more than `int(eval(expr)) == eval(expr)`? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Eric More or less I need to, given a list or set of expressions, disqualify/remove any of those that will contain a non-integer value at any point during evaluation/simplification.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Eric Sorry.. do you know the gameshow "Letters and Numbers" I think it might go by other names in other countries. Anyway, I wanted to see if I could make a script to solve the "number" section of the game. Quick rundown: given six numbers, using four operators (+, -, *, /) as many times as needed, you have to get those numbers as close to a given goal number. So my thinking is that can generate all possible combinations of numbers/operators, to get a solution. But no non-integer division, hence my question. I hope that's a little clearer.

Comment: Just realising now that I could avoid bracketing complications (and the problems with parsing) if I use Reverse Polish Notation, but then just have to be able to parse RPN instead.

Comment: "But no non-integer division" - can you construct an example where simply checking if the result of the division is a whole number is not a sufficient way to check if this occured?

Comment: That would work, yes. But the problem I had was more one of parsing, given that the strings to check would be arbitrary, and there may be some intermediate evaluation that has to be done before getting to the actual division e.g. '(3+4)/2' compared to '3+(4/2)'

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are too many things that could produce such values. For example `**` can be used to compute square roots and generally the contents passed to `eval` could be anything.

I believe using `eval` is not a good approach at all. You could use the [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.parse) function to obtain an [AST (abstract syntax tree)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) that represent the expression, and then write your own simple interpreter to evaluate it. In this interpreter you can do all the checks you want at every step.

---

You would write something like:

```
from ast import *

def simple_expr_eval(expr):
    if not isinstance(expr, Expression):
        raise TypeError('should be an expression')
    return simple_eval(expr.body)

def simple_eval(expr):
    handlers = {
        BinOp: simple_eval_binop,
        UnaryOp: simple_eval_unaryop,
        Num: simple_eval_number,
        # ...
    }
    return handlers[type(expr)](expr)

def simple_eval_binop(binop):
    if binop.op is Mult:
        left = simple_eval(binop.left)
        right = simple_eval(binop.right):
        return left * right
    elif binop is Div:
        # here you could check whether left/right produces a floating point...
        raise ValueError('Floating operation during evaluation')
    # ...
```

It's a bit of work, but not really so much if you only want to handle simple expressions. In these functions you are free to simplify/swap nodes in order to change how the expression is evaluated.

You should also parse the code by specifying the `eval` evaluation mode (i.e. `eval(your_expr, '<fake-filename>', 'eval')`).